# Cassandra ResultSet returns same set of records(same page) with pagination

Tags: python, cassandra, pagination, resultset

I am doing full scan of Cassandra table which has 75 million records. I am using cassandra python driver to connect to cassandra database and below is my code. While iterating ResultSet, the loop is fetching 100 records per page which is fine but it is fetching same 100 records again and again in repeating way. I am new to Cassandra and appreciate if someone can help me.

```py
statement = SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM keyspace.tablename", fetch_size=500)
rows = session.execute(statement)
for row in rows:
    print row.sid, row.sname
```

Comment: what is your table structure & what is the version of Cassandra driver?

Comment: Table contain JSON documents. with primary key column document_id and partitioned by document_id. The Cassandra driver version is 3.1.4